# Approximation in the Plane of Constant Curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, approximation, plane-curves, approximation-theory

In Euclidean space, There is a classic Theorem claims that: The length of every rectifiable curve can be approximated by sufficiently small straight line segment with ends on the curve.

Now, The question is that: Is there a similar thing happen on plane of constant curvature? I.e., **Can the length of  every rectifiable curve on the  plane of constant curvature be approximated by sufficiently small geodesic line segment?**

Comment: Yes, this is normally how the [length of the curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve#Lengths_of_curves) would be defined, if it is not assumed to be smooth.